# Trying to split a string into two integers

Tags: c++

So I want to split a string (entered to the console) into two integers.

The first integer will always be one digit at position `0` in the string. Then, there will be a space. Everything after that space will be the second digit.

Here is my code:

```
struct priority_element
{
    int id;
    int priority;
} priorityQueue[1000];

string input;
cin << input;
priority_element temp;
string priority = input.substr(0, 1);
string id = input.substr(1, input.size());
temp.priority = atoi(priority.c_str());
temp.id = atoi(id.c_str());
priorityQueue[0] = temp;
cout << priorityQueue[0].priority;
cout << priorityQueue[0].id;
```

I included the `priority_element` struct so you could see what it was.
I keep trying to enter a string, something like:

```
5 6
```

or

```
5 5000
```

I can print the `priority (5)`, but printing the `priority` and `id` together like in my example code has the output of `50`.

If I try to print the `id` alone then the output is empty.

Could anyone understand why this is happening?
Thanks!

Comment: You can initialize two variables at once with `cin` like this: `std::cin >> var1 >> var2;`

Comment: `int i, j; std::cin >> i >> j;`

Comment: Why don't you just do `cin >> priority_queue[0].id; cin >> priority_queue[0].priority;`?

Comment: Shouldn't your `cin <<` be `cin >>`?

Comment: When you use `cin >> input`, it only reads one word from the input. If you want to read a whole line, use `getline`.

Comment: Thanks @Barmar! The cin << was just a typo. Using getline worked. I was using cin because eventually my program is going to read line by line from a text file using cin, and I was just testing it with the console.

Answer (score 4):

`std::cin` will stop passing at spaces, so you should read the whole line to `input` by using

```
// cin >> input;
std::getline(cin, input);
```

---

As suggested by others, actually, this can be done simply by:

```
std::cin >> temp.priority >> temp.id;
```

Answer (score 2):

The streams in C++ are made for just this type of thing.

(from iostream)

```
int x,y;
std::cin >> x;
std::cin >> y;
std::cout << x << y << std::endl;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
string id = input.substr(1, input.size());
```

here you got a space not the second digit

English is not my first langage , hope you can understand